# In the given diagram $ABCD$, $AD = BC$ and $AC=BD$. Prove that $PC=PD$

Tags: geometry

In the given diagram $ABCD$, $AD = BC$ and $AC=BD$. Prove that $PC=PD$

Is the question complete or missing some information?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triangles $\triangle(ACD)$ and $\triangle(BDC)$ are mirror congruent, because they have equal sides. It follows that $\angle(ACD)=\angle(BDC)$; hence $\triangle(PCD)$ is isosceles, so that $|PC|=|PD|$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Congruent triangles, isosceles triangle, ...

Comment: Could you please point which triangles should I consider?